# Matching pushpool difficulty with stratum's

Tags: mining-pools, difficulty, stratum, pushpool

I have a new question for you.

I have setup the stratum mining proxy, and all is working fine. (Actually found our first block recently!)
However, I have pushpool running as well, and some of my users still use it based on preference.

How can I be assured that people that use stratum isn't getting more shares than those who's using pushpool? Is there a way to set the difficulty on stratum? 
As of now i set the difficulty manually in pushpool's config file, with `rpc.target.bits`

Help is appriciated!

Answer (score -1):

This is how you change the difficulty in Stratum:

go to mining/subscription.py

change

```
self.connection_ref().rpc('mining.set_difficulty', [16,], is_notification=True)
```

to

```
self.connection_ref().rpc('mining.set_difficulty', [32,], is_notification=True)
```

That will set the difficulty to 32 - or change to whatever value you want.

Comment: Will the 32 in: `self.connection_ref().rpc('mining.set_difficulty', [32,], is_notification=True)`
actually correspond to the SAME difficulty stated in the config of pushpool? So 20 in pushpool = 20 in that line you posted?

Comment: Note that this stratum server does not use the same definition of difficulty as the rest of mining. So if you want difficulty 32 shares, you need to use:

self.connection_ref().rpc('mining.set_difficulty', [31.99951171875,], is_notification=True)